# How to avoid error with Injection of autowired dependencies in Java based configuration?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I use Java based configuration. When I have had only one UserRepository bean, all was working just fine. But when I added another one implementation of UserRepository, I got this error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'answerService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.springapp.mvc.service.NewUserService com.springapp.mvc.service.AnswerService.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'newUserService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.springapp.mvc.repository.UserRepository com.springapp.mvc.service.NewUserService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.springapp.mvc.repository.UserRepository] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [jpaUserRepository, jsonUserRepository]

Here is my configuration:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.springapp.mvc")
@PropertySource("classpath:names.properties")
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/");
    }
}
```

And my service which is using one of UserService implementation:

```
@Service
public class NewUserService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jsonRepo")
    public UserRepository userRepository;

    // methods ommited
}
```

I tried to add `@Qualifier` annotation to `UserRepository userRepository` and to specific implementation:

```
@Repository("jsonRepo")
public class JsonUserRepository implements UserRepository {...}
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Listen to your IDE ... Error creating bean with name 'answerService': ... ... ... Could not autowire field: public com.springapp.mvc.service.NewUserService ... ... ... com.springapp.mvc.service.AnswerService.userService; 

Error creating bean with name 'newUserService':  ... ... Could not autowire field: public com.springapp.mvc.repository.UserRepository com.springapp.mvc.service.NewUserService.userRepository; ... ...... : No unique bean of type [com.springapp.mvc.repository.UserRepository] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [jpaUserRepository, jsonUserRepository]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Repository
@Qualifier("jsonRepo")
public class JsonUserRepository implements UserRepository {...}
```